# How can I determine the class of an XML serialized object in C# before I deserialize it?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a server that accepts requests as XML serialized objects which could be any of 10 or so different Classes.  Of course in order for the server to process the request, it must first de-serialize the XML string back into an object.  To do that, it needs to know what class the object came from to choose the correct de-serializer and re-construct the object.  So it would be good to be able to just quickly inspect the XML string before attempting to de-serialize it to get the object type and then select the appropriate de-serializer.

I have been using the following code, but, like the song goes, "I know there's got to be a better way..."  Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //any class - does not matter - create an object
        SomeClass tc = new SomeClass();
        //populate it
        tc.i = 5;
        tc.s = "Hello World";
        tc.d = 123.456;

        //Serialize it to XML
        StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
        x.Serialize(xml, tc);

        //Extract the Class name and show the XML to the user without de-serializing it
        textBox1.Text = GetClassNameFromXMLSerializedString(xml.ToString());
    }

    private string GetClassNameFromXMLSerializedString(string xml)
    {
        //The class name is somewhere in the xml
        string classname = xml;
        //get the start of class name
        classname = xml.Substring(classname.IndexOf('>') + 4);
        //get the class name which is terminated by a space
        classname = classname.Substring(0, classname.IndexOf(' '));
        //return it
        return classname;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML Deserializer does not need to know what type it is before deserializing. The [MSDN Article about the Deserialize method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) has some useful information about it and of course it has a code snippet, which I've put below.

I think you might have confused yourself with the fact that the server will deserialize it to an object, but then won't know what to do with it. You can always do a `switch case` for the result of the `ReturnedObject.GetType()` method and work out what you need to do with it.

You can just serialize it to an object like this:

```
 var ReturnedObject = XMLSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Then you can go ahead and do

```
 switch (ReturnedObject.getType())
 {
     case MyClass:
         // Insert code here 
     case AnotehrClass:
         //Do something else here for another class
 }
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  I was not clear in my question.  I really just need to know how to process the deserialized object in a switch statement very much like what you suggested.  I like your method better than mine but when I try to duplicate the code with my own similar code, I get a compiler error as follows;"Error 1 A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type F:\Documents and Settings\Tom\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Serialization experiment\Serialization experiment\Form1.cs 48 21 Serialization experiment

Comment: If I convert ReturnedObject.GetType() to a string and switch on that, it looks like it is a great answer.

Comment: Although its true that "The XML Deserializer does not need to know what type it is before deserializing", it looks as if you do need to know the object type when you first create the Deserializer. But I may be missing something.   @Butler1233

Comment: My memory of the XML serializer isn't the best, but I think you might be able to instantiate it with the object type. It's not the nicest way to do it, but I think it should work. I'm much more familiar with the Binary formatter which serialises to binary, which I've found is much more flexible. And you don't have to make parameterless constructors with the Binary one. if you're interested in that one I can give you details about how to use that. If you're sending a raw bytestream over the network it might be better.

Comment: However, if you are using network communication, and if both ends are .Net, you'll have better luck using WCF, which also seems like a huge pain in the ass at first, makes life so easy, mainly because you can interface with the server almost as if it's local code.

Comment: When you say you can instantiate the XMLserializer with the object type suggests that you know the object type.  That's really the question. If you are dealing with different types of objects the question becomes How do you know which Serializer to instantiate so you can deserialize the object......

Comment: private string GetClassNameFromXMLSerializedString(string xml)
        {
            xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(">\r\n<") + 3, 50);//get second XML element
            return xml.Substring(1, xml.IndexOf(' ') - 1);//get class name
        }

Comment: Sorry for th ebad format....private string GetClassNameFromXMLSerializedString(string xml)
        {
            xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(">\r\n<") + 3, 50);//get second XML element
            return xml.Substring(1, xml.IndexOf(' ') - 1);//get class name
        }

Comment: Inference like this is very convenient but sometimes opens an attack vector and in such a case it's better to spoon-feed the expected type for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to you can read the 3rd element like this:

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(GenerateStreamFromString(xml.ToString())))
{
    xr.Read();
    xr.Read();
    xr.Read();

    textBox1.Text =  xr.Name;
}
```

Using this helper function:

```
public static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
{
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
}
```

All checks omitted..

If you want to you can test if the 1st element is `xml` and the 2nd one is empty. 
I'm not really sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

`XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString()); switch (xd.Root.Name.ToString()) { case "Class1": //do something break; case "Class2": //do something break; }`

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted. It would also benefit from explanation.